# Find cost function for given production function

Tags: microeconomics, production-function, optimization, cost, cost-functions

I have the following production function

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=max\{\min\{x_1, x_2), x_3+2x_4\}\}\ge q$$

And I want to find the cost function.

What I think

(1) $P_1+P_2 <P_3$ and $P_3/P_4<1/2$

then $(x_1^*, x_2^*, x_3^*, x_4^*) =(q,q,0,0) $

Cost function is $c(q,w)=q[w_1+w_2]$

(2) $P_1+P_2 <P_4$ and $P_3/P_4>1/2$

then $(x_1^*, x_2^*, x_3^*, x_4^*) =(q,q,0,0) $

Cost function is $c(q,w)=q[w_1+w_2]$

(3) $P_1+P_2 >P_3$ and $P_3/P_4<1/2$

then $(x_1^*, x_2^*, x_3^*, x_4^*) =(0,0,q,0) $

Cost function is $c(q,w)=qw_3$

(4) $P_1+P_2 >P_4/2$ and $P_3/P_4>1/2$

then $(x_1^*, x_2^*, x_3^*, x_4^*) =(0,0,q/2,0) $

Cost function is $c(q,w)=qw_4/2$

I have no idea how to solve such a production function.  But I posted what I tried. Please show me the correct solution and how to solve such a function. Thank you.

Comment: Someone has deleted the answer. Let me share it here: One of the ways to solve this problem is almost the same as the one posted here: https://qr.ae/pvKJuI

Comment: Using this method will give the following cost function for the above production function:

$C(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, q)=q\min\left\{(w_1+w_2),w_3, \dfrac{w_4}{2}\right\}$

where $w_i$ denotes the price (per unit) of input $x_i$, and $q$ is the quantity of output produced.

Comment: Many thanks @Amit

Comment: I am glad that the link I provided is helpful in understanding the approach to solve this question.

Comment: Yes for sure @Amit that question with solution is very clear and explanatory :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually moderator of the econ-stackexchange deleted the answer giving the reason that the "link only" answers are against the rules of the econ-stackexchange. So I was just confirming.